# Why my posts array is empty in SQL wordpress?

Tags: sql, wordpress, shortcode

I am using a shortcode comparing two categories with AND operator. But between two pairs categories, one is working other is not. I have also `print_r` the value on the page. The `[request]` value coming both of the page, but in my desired page `[posts] => Array()` is empty. Here is the requested result,

```
[request] => SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND ( 
  (
                SELECT COUNT(1)
                FROM wp_term_relationships
                WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (82,98,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125,127,128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,149,150,170,196,209,295,296,383)
                AND object_id = wp_posts.ID
            ) = 35
) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'wpdmpro' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_title ASC LIMIT 0, 40
```

But posts array is empty. Here you can see the result both of page result,

https://www.educateoutside.com/wpdm-test/ not working,

https://www.educateoutside.com/wpdm-test-2/, working

Comment: can you share more code?. did you use WP_Query() or get_posts() please share that code with arguments.

Comment: there are lots of code with parameter and condition, i have just shared the query value, do you think this can be code related issue too?